# Why can't I restore this model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am currently having trouble **restoring this model to make a prediction**.

Code:

```py
def neural_network(data):
    with tf.name_scope("network"):
        layer1 = tf.layers.dense(data, 1000, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden_layer1")
        layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 1000, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden_layer2")
        output = tf.layers.dense(layer2, 2, name="output_layer")

        return output


def evaluate():
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        global x
        xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=neural_network(x))
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

    with tf.name_scope("train"):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    with tf.name_scope("exec"):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            for i in range(1, 10):
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={x: np.array(train_data).reshape([-1, 1]), y: label})
                print "Training " + str(i)
                saver = tf.train.Saver()
                saver.save(sess, "saved_models/testing")
                print "Model Saved."


def predict():
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        output = neural_network(x)
        output = tf.nn.softmax(output)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
            # saver = tf.train.Saver()
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
            print sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])})
```

I have tried using `tf.train.Saver()` to restore but also gives the same error.

```
The error given is ValueError: Variable hidden_layer1/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

I have tried setting `reuse=True` for `tf.layers.dense()` but it results in me unable to train the graph (gives the same ValueError as above but asking to set `reuse=None`).

I am guessing it has to do with the graph still existing in the session so when I try to restore it, it detects a duplicate graph. However, I thought this should not happen as the session have already closed.

link to entire code: [gistlink](https://gist.github.com/duemaster/4096af7fc2625e4c4b01cf19e8660464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are loading the variables in the same graph. For testing try to create a new graph and load it. Do something like this:

```py
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
   # Load the graph with the trained states
```

Comment: do you mean modifying my predict() like such?

Comment: `def predict():
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        output = neural_network(x)
        output = tf.nn.softmax(output)

        loaded_graph = tf.Graph()

        with tf.Session(loaded_graph) as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
            # saver = tf.train.Saver()
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
            print sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])})
`

Comment: Not your computer but your kernel

Comment: I am still quite new to tensorflow. You do mean tensorflow kernel right?

Comment: I have also added the link to entire code in the post, if it helps.